# Is it possible to override a Lightswitch application title?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'd like to insert the application version number into my Lightswitch application title bar, but I haven't found anyway to programatically set the application title. Has anyone had any luck doing this?

Comment: There is a Title property in Application.Current.Details, but it doesn't seem to have any relationship to the actual application title. It appears that the Application Name, which is set in the project propoperties and controls the title, is not accessible in code. Good question! I hope there's an answer to this in the release version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is an OOB app, the title can be set in OutOfBrowerSettings.xml

See here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/baf582d9-2a26-41bd-af8b-f515755c2783

And for sizing options as well:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/04ea3682-be6a-4a24-a770-aad0d71ec7e2

If the application is hosted inside a web page, so you just need change the title of the web page to whatever you want (from a post from Microsoft's Lifeng Lu).

Yann

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Lightswitch before but in regular VB.Net you'd just add this to your Form Load event:

```
Me.Text = Me.Text & " " & Me.ProductVersion.ToString()
```

Comment: I expect that this would probably work, but Lightswitch solutions hide many of the underlying silverlight events. I'm currently trying to find this event so I can test this.